# How to program doors to automatically lock at certain time?

Tags: locks, door, alarm, security

We have had a rash of break-ins and thefts from our neighborhood vehicles, and of course -- it did not matter until I became a victim.  Apparently, thieves come along late at night, check your door handles, and if they are unlocked -- help themselves to your property.

I know, LOCK YOUR DOORS.  Deterrent #1.  Also, I know I can have flood lights, surveillance, car alarms, and all of that.  However, there is also the human element that may forget to lock those doors and activate the alarm one night with an armful of groceries, and kids in tow.

That said -- the lazy engineering side of me believes there MUST be some security system or custom method to program your car/truck doors to LOCK at a specific time each night (if your keys are not inside).  **Does this exist?**

With home automation, I can have lights turn on or off when I come home or drive away, I have a robotic vaccum that cleans my floors every night, and I have Amazon/Google Home which do tons of automated things for me -- not to mention, we have auto locks when cars reach a certain speed.  Makes sense that the automotive industry has this time-based automation possibility as well.

Any leads would be great!

Comment: What kind of car is it? Some domestics auto lock after x minutes. There are probably aftermarket solutions as well.

Comment: @Ben 2006 GMC Sierra 1500.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could integrate an Arduino or Raspberry Pi solution here.

Comment: A timer driven from when the interior lights go out that kicks the lock circuit...

Comment: There is a safety/usability aspect to this, say you are out at night running an unexpected errand or on a road trip.  You get out of your car to fill up with fuel and the timer hits. your keys are now locked in the car. you could try a fingerbot attached to your keys to activate the lock button.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuv1oUxCd9M for what a fingerbot is